# How to set default Ansible username/password for SSH connection?

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible and I have this configuration in my inventory/all:

```
[master]
192.168.1.10 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant

[slave]
192.168.1.11 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant
192.168.1.12 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant

[app]
192.168.1.13 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant

[all:children]
master
slave
```

I don't want to repeat all the parameters for each new instance. How can I configure them just in one place? Is there any file with these parameters?

Comment: `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: @ceejayoz Could you explain a little

Comment: I'm not an Ansible admin, and the docs are cloudy on the subject ([is this a "variable" or a "parameter" and is there a difference?](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters)) but it looks like you can somehow define variables at the group level.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can add following section to your inventory file:

```
[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant
```

**Note:** Before Ansible 2.0 `ansible_user` was `ansible_ssh_user`.

Comment: Above Ansible 2.0,  it should be: 
`[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_port=22
ansible_user=admin`

Comment: @zx1986 where did you read that?

Comment: @030 here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters

Comment: Note that port 22 is the default for `ansible_port`, so you don't need to explicitly specify it unless different.  Interested if anyone knows how to apply variables to more than one group at a time (but not 'all'), comma separation doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @WilliamTurrell a little late but.. you can create a group of groups (with the :children modifier) and then set the variables afterwards (with the :vars modifier).

Comment: This solution also apply to Ansible 2.9 (currently available)

Answer (score 29):

### Group Variables

You can set variables that apply to all hosts by using the [playbook layout](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout) specified in Ansible's [Best Practices](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html) document and creating a `group_vars/all` file where you [define them](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#group-and-host-variables).

```
---
# file: group_vars/all
ansible_connection: ssh 
ansible_ssh_user: vagrant 
ansible_ssh_pass: vagrant
```

[edit] I'm confused though at what you're trying to do though.  You shouldn't need to specify the Ansible user or password in the inventory.  If you're using Vagrant you definitely don't, and if you're calling Ansible from the command-line you can specify the user with `--user=vagrant` and have it ask for the password with `--ask-pass`.

Comment: I only need to do a better organization of my infrastructure. If always I will use vagrant:vagrant I want to put it configuration in some place where Ansible load by default, but I don't know where. Every connection to be executed has to use it.

Comment: Must the file be named `group_vars/all/main.yml` or simply `group_vars/all`?

Comment: this one worked for me after installing `sshpass` - `"you must install the sshpass program"`

Comment: @realtebo The file must be named `group_vars/all`.

Comment: -k for ask pass is not a lot of fun for "all" when each host has a different password. Yes you need sshpass, and yes you probably need to seed known_hosts if you have never connected before ~\.ssh\config is the way to go.

Comment: @realtebo both work. You can use former to separate variables that needs encryption from other variables

Answer (score 10):

Add below to inventory hosts.

For  Ansible <2.0:

```
[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant 
ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant
```

For  [Ansible >=2.0](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters):

```
[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh # actually default mode smart is OK
ansible_user=vagrant
ansible_pass=vagrant # or ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant
```

Comment: The link mentions `ansible_ssh_pass`, not `ansible_pass`.

Comment: According the documentation it should be `ansible_password`. Tested it and that seems to work.

Answer (score 8):

I think that it is better to use ssh key installation onto all the servers across the pull.
You should run ssh-copy-id only per node and install your ssh key everywhere for ansible's ability to log in using your ssh key. It will be more secure not to save passwords into playbook/inventory.

For doing this you should [generate your ssh key pair](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)  and run ssh-copy-id for all the servers afterwards.

Comment: If someone can steal the password from your configuration file they'll likely be able to your ssh keys as well. And this has nothing at all to do with answering OPs question. This question wasnt asking for opinions on alternatives.

Comment: @MuhFugen
> How can I configure them just in one place? Is there any file with these parameters?



This is an exact phrase which leaves the door for the opinion as well as response gives an understanding of right direction.
Stealing configuration (that could live in the git repo somewhere) is not the same as stealing private key.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I've only tested this on OSX.  Based on the various docs, I expect it to work on other platforms.

"project directory" refers to the base directory for the Vagrant project -- the directory that contains `Vagrantfile`.

**Ansible Inventory file auto-generated by Vagrant:**

Vagrant [creates an inventory file](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_intro.html#the-inventory-file) with the default Ansible connection vars. Look for it in `<project directory>/.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory`.

This file will be regenerated by Vagrant as-needed, so manual edits will get overwritten. However, according to the Vagrant docs, you can specify multiple machines, group vars, etc in `Vagrantfile` and they'll be added to this inventory file.

**Configure Ansible to default to this inventory file:**

To make this file the default used by the `ansible` command when you're in the project directory (on the host), add an `ansible.cfg` file in your project directory with these contents, changing the path as needed:

```
[defaults]
inventory = ./path/to/inventory
```

To confirm that this inventory file is being used, look for it as the default reported by ansible:

*(from within the project directory)*

`$ ansible | grep inventory
ERROR! Missing target hosts
  -i INVENTORY, --inventory-file=INVENTORY
                        specify inventory host path (default=./.vagrant/provis
                        ioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory) or`

To confirm your hosts:

`$ ansible all --list-hosts
  hosts (2):
    master
    slave`

**Using Ansible with these hosts:**

From within the project directory, you should then be able to use `ansible` as normal with the hosts that you defined in `Vagrantfile`.

For example:

```
ansible slave -a 'hostname'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the right variables. You need to use:

```
# yml syntax
ansible_user: myusername
ansible_password: mypassword

# inventory syntax
host ansible_user=myusername ansible_password=mypassword
```

You need to read very carefully, because `ansible_ssh_password` and `ansible_ssh_user` do not work in version: ansible 2.9.6

Answer (score 1):

Below is the steps for how to Set default Ansible username/password for SSH connection

ansible.cfs configuration will be

```
$ cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]
inventory = ./inventory

[privilege_escalation]
become = True
become_method = sudo
become_user = root
```

Inventory file will be

```
$ cat inventory
[App1]
10.163.128.21

[App1:vars]
ansible_password=*************
ansible_ssh_user=Appuser1
host_key_checking=False
```

ansible execution success result

```
$ ansible App1 -m ping
10.163.128.21 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```